# Scala XML processing is skipping a value

Tags: xml, scala

I am trying to develop a rest api in scala that grabs the xml of a couple of rss feeds and then displays them in json. So far I can display them as text, which is fine, but I can't get the author to show up. I am creating a list of the articles (where Article is a case class), and searching the xml to provide the values for the Article class.

```
<item>
  <title>Chinese TV Star Apologizes For Remarks Critical Of Mao</title>
  <description>Bi Fujian, one of the country's most popular television presenters, recently ran afoul of his employer, state-run CCTV, for a parody song he performed at a private banquet.</description>
  <pubDate>Thu, 09 Apr 2015 12:51:15 -0400</pubDate>
  <link>http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2015/04/09/398534903/chinese-tv-star-apologizes-for-remarks-critical-of-mao?utm_medium=RSS&amp;utm_campaign=news</link>
  <guid>http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2015/04/09/398534903/chinese-tv-star-apologizes-for-remarks-critical-of-mao?utm_medium=RSS&amp;utm_campaign=news</guid>
  <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>Bi Fujian, one of the country's most popular television presenters, recently ran afoul of his employer, state-run CCTV, for a parody song he performed at a private banquet.</p><p><a href="http://www.npr.org/templates/email/emailAFriend.php?storyId=398534903">&raquo; E-Mail This</a></p>]]></content:encoded>
  <dc:creator>Scott Neuman</dc:creator>
</item>
```

This is an example of the xml I am parsing. Here is the code I am using to parse it:

```
def xml = XML.loadString(retrieveArticles("http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1007")) ++ XML.loadString(retrieveArticles("http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1003")) ++ XML.loadString(retrieveArticles("http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1001"))

    val articles = (xml \\ "item").foldLeft(List[Article]())((ls,item) => Article((item \ "title").text,
        (item \ "dc:creator").text,
        (item \ "pubDate").text,
        (item \ "link").text,
        (item \ "description").text) :: ls)
```

All of the other values are being processed correctly. Author is the only value that is not showing up. When I call the api to show the articles, this is what I get:

```
Title: Chinese TV Star Apologizes For Remarks Critical Of Mao,
Author: ,
Date Published: Thu, 09 Apr 2015 12:51:00 -0400,
Link: http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2015/04/09/398534903/chinese-   tv-star-apologizes-for-remarks-critical-of-mao?utm_medium=RSS&utm_campaign=news,
Contents: Bi Fujian, one of the country's most popular television presenters, recently ran afoul of his employer, state-run CCTV, for a parody song he performed at a private banquet.
```

Why is the author not being shown when all of the other values are displayed with no problems?

Comment: @mohit was the edit to remove the json tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon `:` in XML is a special character that separates a label from its (optional) prefix.  So, the label of the element you're looking for is actually `creator`, not `dc:creator`.  Read about prefixes in XML [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).

If you need to use the prefix as well as the label for selecting elements, you can use the `prefix` property.  Here's a simplified version of the problem you're facing:

```
val xml = <root><foo:bar/><qux:bar/></root>
xml \\ "foo:bar" // No elements found!  This is the wrong selector.
xml \\ "bar" // NodeSeq(<foo:bar/>, <qux:bar/>)
(xml \\ "bar").filter(_.prefix == "foo") //NodeSeq(<foo:bar/>)
```

So, in your example, you either just want to use `(item \ "creator")` for the author, or also filter to the `dc` prefix if necessary.

As a side note, you can use `map` instead of `foldLeft` in your code, which would be a little neater and more idiomatic:

```
(xml \\ "item").map { item => Article(
    (item \ "title").text,
    (item \ "creator").text,
    (item \ "pubDate").text,
    (item \ "link").text,
    (item \ "description").text
)}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked without having to add the filter. Also, thanks for the suggestion about using map. I'm still trying to learn how to make my Scala code more idiomatic as I came over from Java.